# What is $2^{32} - 1$ in decimal notation?

Tags: decimal-expansion

I came across decimal notation, and surprisingly I have never heard of it. I have heard of *scientific notation* and just thought this was decimal notation. However, when I want to find a definition on the internet, it isn’t clear. Could somebody please explain to me? This looks to be a very basic thing in maths which I should know by now so I don’t understand why I don’t know it.

As an example, what is $2^{32} - 1$ in decimal notation? Is this also the same as *decimal expansion*? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `Is this also the same as decimal expansion?` Yes.

Comment: $2^{32} - 1 = 4294967296 - 1 = 4294967295$.

Comment: $4294967295$ I reckon

Comment: Oh. Ok. I thought this was something I completely missed, but might have been something I didn’t remember in primary school.

Comment: Or, as one said back in the [new math days](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Math), what is the *decimal numeral* equivalent of $2^{32}-1?$ Here the use of "numeral" is crucial, because it was deemed that grade school children should always make the distinction between a number and a numeral representation of that number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They could simply mean the usual base 10 representation.
$$
(d_m \dotsc d_0)_{10} = \sum_{k=0}^{m} d_k 10^k
$$
thus
$$
2^{32}-1 = 4294967295 = (11111111111111111111111111111111)_2
$$
where I assumed $32$ to be given in base $10$ already, as no base has been provided for it. :)

Comment: Thank you very much. It would have been very embarrassing for me to move on to integrals and derivatives without even knowing what decimal notation/expansion is... jeez... anyway, congratulations :) $$(+1) \ \ \color{green}{\checkmark}$$ (Wait, I need to wait $7$ minutes before I can tick u.)

Answer (score 2):

***Decimal Notation*** uses successive non-negative powers of $10$ with coefficients in the range $0-9$, as @mvw has very nicely explained in his answer.

As for a specific example, one has:

$$\begin{align} 2^{32} - 1 &= (2^{16} - 1)(2^{16} + 1) \\ &= (2^8 - 1)(2^8 + 1)(2^{16} + 1) \\ &= (2^4 - 1)(2^4 + 1)(2^8 + 1)(2^{16} + 1) \\ &= (2^2 - 1)(2^2 + 1)(2^4 + 1)(2^8 + 1)(2^{16} + 1) \\ &= (2^1 - 1)(2^1 + 1)(2^2 + 1)(2^4 + 1)(2^8 + 1)(2^{16} + 1) \\ &= 1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 17 \cdot 257 \cdot (2^{16} + 1) \\ &= 1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 17 \cdot 257 \cdot 65537 \\ &= 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 17 \cdot 257 \cdot 65537 \\ &= 15 \cdot 17 \cdot 257 \cdot 65537 \\ &= 255 \cdot 257 \cdot 65537 \\ &= 65535 \cdot 65537 \\ &= \boxed{4294967295} \tag 1 \end{align}$$

Of course I did all the multiplications in my head!  ***Yeah, right!!!***

Comment: If you want to have a quick approximation in your head, you could just notice that $2^{10}$ is a bit more than $1000$. So $2^{32}$ is 4 times 1000 times 1000 times 1000. A bit more than 4 billions.

Comment: @EricDuminil:  what I really wanted was to see how far I could go with the $2^{2n} - 1 = (2^n - 1)(2^n + 1)$ idea!

Comment: Just.... wow....